# Does there exist any continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

My attempt to the problem is first I intend to make a perfect nowhere dense set of irrational numbers of measure $0$ like cantor set(and that I guess we could do)..now make such type of function like cantor function on that closed interval end with irrational endpoints from which we initially start work to make such cantor set types set consisting with irrationals only.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Hint: construct $f$ on individual intervals $[n,n+1]$ so that $f([n,n+1]) = f([n+1,n+2])$ but the rationals in those two intervals are sent to different points.

Comment: @Greg Martin ok i understood that but how can you say such function such that f([n,n+1])=[n+1,n+2] ??

Comment: Did you try wild guesses like $f : x \mapsto \sin(\frac{x}{\pi}) \cdot e^{x^2}$ ? $f$ seems to be a good quandidate.

Comment: @Greg Martin i actually understand after construct such function f:[0,1] -[0,1] which satisfy my property then after shifting and translating we can do that i understand that....

Comment: @Olivier Roche: following your hint  got the (tamer)  $x\cdot \sin \pi x$  that can be shown to work.

Answer (score 7):

There is a continuous map of the unit interval onto unit square (so called Peano curve)
Compose it with the projection onto $x$ -axis.
One gets a continuous map from the unit interval onto unit interval such that inverse image of each point is uncountable. Hence, for each rational there must be an irrational mapped into it.

Comment: that's a fantastic answer....

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be defined on $[0,1]$ with $$g(0)=0, g(1/\sqrt3)=1, g(2/3)=0,g(1)=1,$$ and the function is linear between these values. Then define $$f(x)=g(x-\lfloor x\rfloor )+\lfloor x\rfloor.$$

You can replace $1/\sqrt3,2/3$ with any pair $0<a<b<1$ with exactly one of $a,b$ rational.

Then for any real $r,$ $f^{-1}(r)$ has at least three elements (more if $r$ is an integer) and at least one of these elements is irrational.

Assume $r=n+y$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $0\leq y<1.$

If $y=0,$ $f(n-1+1/\sqrt3)=r.$

If $r$ is irrational, then $f(x)=r$ for $x=n+2/3+y/3,$ which is irrational.

If $r$ is rational and not an integer, then $f(x)=r$ for $x=n+y/\sqrt3,$ which is irrational.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $g$ is defined as $g(x)=3(x-2/3)$ for $x\in[2/3,1].$ How could the limit not be $1$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea:

Consider the following maps from $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $[0,1]$

$$\phi((a_n)) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n}{2^n} \\
\psi((a_n)) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1+a_n}{3^{n^2}}$$

Both $\phi$, $\psi$ are continuous, and moreover, $\phi$ is surjective and $\psi $ is a homeomorphism on the image   $K \colon =\operatorname{Im}(\psi)\subset [0,1] \backslash \mathbb{Q}$. Now let $f\colon K \to \mathbb{R}$, $f = \phi\circ \psi^{-1}$, and extend $f$  with Tiezte to $[0,1]$.

$\bf{Added:}$ Inspired by the solution of @Thomas Andrews, here is another solution:

$$f(x) = \left[\frac{x}{2\pi}\right]\cdot\sin x$$

I'll leave the verification as an exercise.

$\bf{Added:}$ Probably a lot of hightly oscilating functions ( like $e^x \sin x$) satisfy the property but checking that can be delicate.  However, it is not that difficult for the function
$$f(x) = x \cdot \sin 2\pi x$$
(inspired by the observation of @Olivier Roche:, )
Indeed, the fibres of $f$ are infinite, but in each fibre there are only finitely many rational numbers-- this because the degree of the algebraic number $\cos 2 r \pi$ is  $\frac{1}{2} \phi(m)$, where $m$ is the denominator of $r$. Now $\phi(m) \to \infty$ as $m\to \infty$.

Comment: Tietz requires $K$ to be closed, if you mean this theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem?wprov=sfti1

Comment: $K$ is compact, homeomorphic to the Cantor set. That's the theorem, and can be proved by hand for closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, extend linearly on the open segments of the complement.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about the $n^2$ part of it.

Answer (score -1):

Each number $x$ in $[0,1]$ can be represented as $\sum{\frac{a_k}{2^k}}$ where $a_k = 0$ or $1$. Define $f(x) = \sum{\frac{a_{2k+1}}{2^k}}$. Then it is easy to see that $f$ is continuous and onto $[0,1]$. Further, for any point $y\in [0,1]$ there are uncountable many $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. Hence, there must be an irrational $x$ with this property. Lastly, one extends $f$ on other intervals by proper shift.

Comment: In binary, $1$ could be expressed as either $1.000...$ or $0.111...$, just as it could also be expressed as $0.999...$ in base $10$. So, the representation is ambiguous for the number $1$.

Comment: I'm not sure this is well defined because some numbers have two representations.  At a minimum, that requires proof.  It's not obvious to me that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: thanks @Salcio but can you tell me how you got the idea ??are you familiar with this types of example??

Comment: This is not continuous at $1/2.$ From the right, the limit is $0.$ From the left, the limit is $1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - form the left and the right limit is $1/2$. The function is continuous of course - if $x$ is close to $y$ they have to have identical many "first" $a_k$'s. The only exception is for sequences ending with $0$ versus ending with $1$ where we still have continuity.

Comment: “Of course?” When $x_n=\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1} \frac1{2^k}$ then $x_n\to 1/2,$ and $f(x_n)\to 1.$ If you meant $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{2k-1}}{2^k},$ then you get a problem at the left and right limit at $\frac14.$ It is not continuous, and merely asserting it is does not make it so. @Salcio

Comment: It is not $\sum \frac{1}{2^k}$ but $\sum\frac{a_{2k+1}}{2^k}$. Think about this in this way - if $x=\sum\frac{a_k}{2^k}$ and $y=\sum\frac{b_k}{2^k}$ and $x$ is "close" to $y$ then their first terms must be the same. To not be confused, if  expansion is not unique pick the finte one (so their are unique).